# How can we optimize the following code for If Else Optimization in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

Can anyone please help to optimize this code to reduce no of if_else statement Switch Case not possible here as Sonar is showing major defects and NpathComplexity.

```
if (status != null) {
            if (MDOConstants.DOCREATED.equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
                return null;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                    && MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                    && MDOConstants.GCSS_REQUESTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_REQUESTED;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.GCSS_ISSUED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_REQUESTED;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED_OR_NEW_PICKUPDATE_NEEDED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
            } else if (MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                    && MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD_TECHNICAL.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD;
            } else if (MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                     && MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD_OUTSIDE_MDO.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
                return MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD;
            } else if (MDOConstants.DOISSUED.equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
                return MDOConstants.DOISSUED;
            }
        }
```

Comment: MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status) store the result of this in some bool variable since you are using it multple times it might reduce execution time

Comment: I like to declare arrays for each specific solutions. So an Array with every `MDOCostants` that can take `subStatus` to return `INPROGRESS` (and so on for other return), you just need to check if it is contained in the array (careful on the comparator to ignore the case). And you will only have on condition per return.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should not refactor this code because of bad performance; or sonar complaining.

You should refactor it for the simple reason that stuff like this is **unreadable**. One can hide 3, 5 typos in such code, and dozens of people would overlook that.

So, what you want to do: apply the [single layer of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle.

So, a rework could look like this:

```
public Whatever findWhateverForPotentiallyNull(String status) {
  if (status == null) {
    return null;

  return findWhatEverFor(status.toUpperCase());
}

private Whatever findWhateverFor(String ucStatus) {
  if (ucStatus.equals(DOCREATED)) {
    return null;
  }

  if (ucStatus.equals(INPROGRESS)) {
    return findWhateverForSubStatus(substatus);
  }
```

... and so on. Notes:

- Using `equals()` is less expensive than `equalsIgnoreCase()`; so instead of doing the later all the time; simply make sure that your incoming status has the same casi-ness as your constants
- I suggest to use static imports for all those constants; the class name is repeated so often there; so it has really no value there; to the contrary; it makes reading harder.
- Yes - you really go in and replace that lengthy if/else tree with a whole list of little private helper methods. The key thing is: simple, short methods can be read and understand 10 times quicker than anything that is substantially bigger.

Beyond the pure refactoring:

- Using **Strings** for status ... sounds like bad practice. Java is a strongly typed language, and you should strive to use specific classes to model your core data; instead of passing around strings all over the place!
- And, as mentioned in some comment: you could consider to use other kinds of "lookup" here; for example by using lists of potential states; or maps; or something alike.

Comment: This is really a nice solution! Mainly because it allows for 2 great things to happen, one is it allows the code to be read and comprehended easier, and the second is that it allows for VERY easy status and sub-status expansions in the future!.. My solution greatly simplified the OP's code, but it is not a scalable solution. This solution will scale nicely!

Comment: You are welcome. Still, you took the time to really dive into his input to dissect that!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this

```
if (status != null)
{
    if (MDOConstants.DOCREATED.equals(status)) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if(MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equals(status)) 
    {
        if(MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.equals(subStatus) || 
            MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.equals(subStatus) ||
            MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.equals(subStatus) ||
            MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.equals(subStatus) || 
            MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED.equals(subStatus) ||
            MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED_OR_NEW_PICKUPDATE_NEEDED.equals(subStatus))
        {
            return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
        } 
        else if(MDOConstants.GCSS_REQUESTED.equals(subStatus) ||
            MDOConstants.GCSS_ISSUED.equals(subStatus))
        {
            return MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_REQUESTED;
        }
    }  
    else if(MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD.equals(status))
    {
        if(MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD_TECHNICAL.equals(subStatus) ||
            MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD_OUTSIDE_MDO.equals(subStatus))
        {
            return MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD;
        }
    } 
    else if(MDOConstants.DOISSUED.equals(status))
    {
        return MDOConstants.DOISSUED;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sure helps .. but just a bit; as you are addressing only one concern out of many.

Answer (score 1):

if that is your exact business logic, contrary to all the return paths above, your code actually only returns 5 distinct values, one being null and then the other 4 are statuses.

Only 2 of all your sub statuses even make a difference at all in the status outcome as well.

if the above code is correct, then this code will achieve the exact same outcome:

```
if (status == null || MDOConstants.DOCREATED.equalsIgnoreCase(status))
    return null;


if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status))
{
    if (MDOConstants.GCSS_REQUESTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus) || MDOConstants.GCSS_ISSUED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus))
        return MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_REQUESTED;
    else
        return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS
}
else if (MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
    return MDOConstants.MNLHNDLD;
else if (MDOConstants.DOISSUED.equalsIgnoreCase(status))
    return MDOConstants.DOISSUED;

//Maybe have some default if all else fails here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like GhostCat said, I would not update this for the bad reasons. But I small reviews for your futur codes using this kind of logic, I will use a small block here

```
if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                && MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
    return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
} else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                 && MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
     return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
} else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                 && MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
     return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
} else if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                 && MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
     return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
}
```

This is redondant. You are always doing the same check first. Just do it once an inside this block, do the specific test.

```
if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
    if(MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
        return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    } else if (MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
         return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    } else if (MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
         return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    } else if (MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
         return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    }
}
```

Then, you have a lot of `return`, so you could store the result to return, this is easier to keep track (but this is personal).

And of course, you return only a few different values, you could use one big condition

```
if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
    if(MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus) ||  
               MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus) || 
               MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) || 
               MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus)) {
         return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    }
}
```

At last, I like to write this using Collection or Arrays.

```
static final List<String> STATUS_IN_PROGRESS = Arrays.asList(
      MDOConstants.MDO_Stored.toLowerCase(), 
      MDOConstants.GCSS_SUBMITTED.toLowerCase(),
      MDOConstants.PENDING_TASKS.toLowerCase(), 
      MDOConstants.ISSUANCE_OK.toLowerCase()
);

if (MDOConstants.INPROGRESS.equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
    if(STATUS_IN_PROGRESS.contains(subStatus.toLowerCase()){
         return MDOConstants.INPROGRESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating `HashMap<Condition,String>`

```
class Condition
{
    String status;
    String subStatus;

    public Condition(String s, String subS)
    {
        status = s;
        subStatus = subS;
    }

    public boolean equals(Condition c)
    {
         return c.status.equalsIgnoreCase(status)
                && c.subStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(subStatus);
    }
}

map.put(new Condition(MDOConstants.INPROGRESS, MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED), MDOConstants.INPROGRESS);
//...
//...

map.get(new Condition(MDOConstants.INPROGRESS, MDOConstants.DEADLINE_PASSED)); // This will give you result.
```

Of course, there is room for improvement, but you might get some hint.